# Ehresmann connection and (Koszul) connections on base manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Once we define an Ehresmann connection over the double tangent space, how does this explicitly determine canonically a (Koszul) connection on the base manifold?

Given a smooth manifold $ M $, let $ TM $  be the tangent bundle. The double tangent space is defined as $ T(TM) $.

An *Ehresmann connection* on a fiber bundle $ \pi: E \to M $ with typical fiber $ F $ is a smooth distribution $ H $ of the tangent bundle $ TE $ which is complementary to the vertical bundle $ VE $, i.e. $ TE = VE \oplus H $, and invariant under the action of the structure group of the bundle.

For the tangent bundle, an Ehresmann connection gives us a way to differentiate vector fields along the directions of other vector fields.

Now, let's focus on the *Koszul connection*. Given a smooth manifold $ M $ with a Riemannian metric $ g $, a Koszul connection on $ M $ is a map

$$\nabla: \Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TM) $$

that satisfies the Leibniz rule and metric compatibility with $ g $.

Given the Ehresmann connection over the double tangent space, I am interested in the canonical determination of a Koszul connection on the base manifold.

**The question now is how to make this connection between the Ehresmann connection on $ T(TM) $ and the Koszul connection on the base manifold $ M $ explicit.**

Any insights on this relationship would be greatly appreciated!